# How do I use the "Award" Schema for an Organization, not a Person?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

The company I work for just won an award and I'd like to mark up the site with Schema.org for that award.

I found the documentation for attributing an award to a `Person`, but I couldn't find any where online where you can mark it up as an `Organization`.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, is the mark up the same as it would be for a `Person`, just switch out the `Person` attribute with `Organization`?

Comment: Is the award for a specific project of this organization? If yes, what kind of project?

Comment: The company is a dealer of a product and we won "Dealer of the Year." So, not really a project, just a general award for our industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>This doesn’t seem to be possible.</del> It’s possible since Schema.org [version 2.0](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.0).

<del>The [`award` property](https://schema.org/award) is only defined for `CreativeWork` and `Person`.</del>

<del>I [filed an issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/365) to ask if it can be broadened.</del> The [`award` property](http://schema.org/award) was broadened, so now it’s also defined/allowed for [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) and [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product).